# Select all elements containing the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate all elements that have id '#response_is_accepted' and be able to change their value to something. ie: val(1). 
I tried but my attempts are failing ie: (in js file)

```
$('#response_is_accepted').each(function(i, obj) {
            alert($(this).text());
        });
```

it always gives me undefined or blank in my alert.

```
            <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_response" id="edit_response_113" action="/responses/113" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
<div class="form-group hidden response_is_accepted"><input class="hidden form-control" type="hidden" value="0" name="response[is_accepted]" id="response_is_accepted" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Response" class="btn btn-default" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right is-accepted" aria-label="Left Align" >Accept</button>

jeje | about 13 hours ago
</form>


<br>
<br>
<br> <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_response" id="edit_response_112" action="/responses/112" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
<div class="form-group hidden response_is_accepted"><input class="hidden form-control" type="hidden" value="0" name="response[is_accepted]" id="response_is_accepted" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Response" class="btn btn-default" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right is-accepted" aria-label="Left Align" >Accept</button>

jeje | about 15 hours ago
</form>


<br>
sa<br>
<br> <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_response" id="edit_response_111" action="/responses/111" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
<div class="form-group hidden response_is_accepted"><input class="hidden form-control" type="hidden" value="0" name="response[is_accepted]" id="response_is_accepted" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Response" class="btn btn-default" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right is-accepted" aria-label="Left Align" >Accept</button>

jeje | about 15 hours ago
</form>
```

Help please

Comment: ID name MUST be unique, otherwise use class instead

Comment: Guys, look at his HTML. He's got the `response_is_accepted` in the class already, he just needs to use the proper selector, as I answered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You are right. I just have one question: I couldnt print the value in alert for each item. I am using this code: $('.response_is_accepted').each(function(i, obj) { alert($(this).val()); }); It is iterating 3 times and thats what i want, but its not just showing the val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i'm not sure what selector you want exactly. But, seeing on your code, you refer to ID, unfortunately ID name must be unique. If you wanna get the input value, then you could use `$('.response_is_accepted')`, but this selector are available for `<div>`, then to get the value of input, you can use `.find()` as following code :

```
 $('.response_is_accepted').each(function(){
    alert($(this).find('input').val());     
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
$('#response_is_accepted')
```

With:

```
$('.response_is_accepted')
```

The elements in your HTML have `"response_is_accepted"` in their `class`, not as `id`, so you'll need to use the class selector (`.`)

In case you only want the `<input>` elements, use this instead:

```
$('.response_is_accepted input.form-control')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You are right. I just have one question: I couldnt print the value in alert for each item. I am using this code: $('.response_is_accepted').each(function(i, obj) {
    alert($(this).val());
   }); It is iterating 3 times and thats what i want, but its not just showing the val.

Comment: @Cerbrus `$('.response_is_accepted')` refer to `<div>`, not input. I'm guess he want to get the input value

Comment: Yeah I can see all the attributes value. but I actually need to change the value of each element, and thats why i need to access them

Comment: @jumbo_burger : see edited post by Cerbrus. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

In jquery:

```
$(document).each(
"#response_is_accepted",
function(){
    $(this).attr("val",1);
);
```

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)